# Mysql date function in QueryDSL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, querydsl

Here is my sql

```
select count(*) date(date) as pub_date from table group by pub_date;
```

[DateExpression](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/expr/DateExpression.html) do not have a function to get date only. The date column in table is `DATETIME`, I just want to group by `DATE` only, but how in querydsl ?

**EIDT**

Done by `DateTemplate.create(Date.class, "date({0})", $.date)`

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `SQLExpressions::date`. The resulting expression can be used as a parameter to the groupBy or other methods of a `com.querydsl.sql.SQLQuery`.

```
import com.querydsl.sql.SQLExpressions;
SQLExpressions.date(QTable.table.date)
```

Answer (score -1):

For date only need to cast it in group by as below,
Try ;

```
 select count(date), date as pub_date from table group by CAST(date AS DATE);
```

Comment: This is not QueryDSL

Answer (score -1):

try

```
to_date(date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

with the second parameter being whatever format you need.

Comment: How to do this in QueryDSL ? DateTimeExpression create ?